# Why does my SQL statement show unknown column in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I do not understand why I get an error saying "Unknown column 'cyclist.ISO_id' in 'where clause'"

```
SELECT name, gender, height, weight FROM Cyclist LEFT JOIN Country ON Cyclist.ISO_id = Country.ISO_id WHERE cyclist.ISO_id = 'gbr%';
```

Comment: In local server it is not work or in host server ? Which `OS` are you used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your table name is `Cyclist`, not `cyclist` - capital `C`. In your `WHERE` clause your're therefore referencing the column of a table which does not exist.

Comment: Well, I guess that is the normal SO behavior. Other basically add the same answer but want theirs to be accepted. So they downvote you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) (with my emphasis):

> Although database, table, and trigger names are not case sensitive on
>   some platforms, **you should not refer to one of these using different
>   cases within the same statement**. The following statement would not
>   work because it refers to a table both as my_table and as MY_TABLE:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE MY_TABLE.col=1;
```

> Column, index, stored routine, and event names are not case sensitive
>   on any platform, nor are column aliases.

So use either `cyclist` or `Cyclist` but **consistently**.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly relevant with OS. Naming Conventions are case sensitive in Unix whereas not in windows OS. You can change the parameter value of lower_case_table_names system variable to 0/2 depending on OS. The detail explanation is available at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html